# По какой формуле рассчитывается dpi устройства?

Tags: android

Предположим я хочу рассчитать dpi или ppi для Nexus 5. Данные можно взять [отсюда](https://design.google.com/devices/). Как там указано он равняется 445. Но если dpi не знаешь заранее, как его можно рассчитать зная остальные данные?
Пробую считать по разным формулам, значение не совпадает для разных девайсов.

Comment: Измерить длину экрана линейкой, перевести в дюймы, узнать в документации количество пикселей по вертикали, поделить.

Comment: @VladD пробовал делать так для Nexus 5 не совпадает значение.

Comment: Значит документация врёт. ppi — это именно количество пикселей на дюйм.

Comment: @VladD По формуле по вертикали получается ~446,5, а по горизонтали 450. Dpi тогда среднее значение?

Comment: Ну, хм. Это значит, что пиксель не квадратный :) Как считается в этом случае — не знаю :(

Comment: @iamtihonov гляньте ответ =)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как получить точную плотность пикселей на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608243/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-android)

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм можно подсмотреть в [моем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608243/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android).

Единственная поправка - значение диагонали экрана должно быть `4.95f` (см. параметр `my_LCD_Diagonal`)