# Как получить точную плотность пикселей на Android

Tags: java, android, экран, display, dpi

Как можно на Android получить точную плотность пикселей?

Сейчас использую следующий код:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi, 2);
double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / dm.ydpi, 2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);
Log.d("debug", "Screen inches : " + screenInches);
```

Его минус в том, что `dm.xdpi` и `dm.ydpi` возвращают не точные значения плотности, а табличную плотность, к которой наиболее близка реальная плотность.

В моем случае телефон 5 дюймов 720*1280, реальная плотность 294, но код выдает мне плотность на уровне 320 и, как следствие, неверный размер экрана в дюймах.

Как мне получить реальную плотность?

Comment: Попробуйте [так](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166501/getting-the-screen-density-programmatically-in-android#comment32614937_3166582): `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metric‌​s);`

Comment: getRealMetrics так же неработает, в результате получил то же что и ранее. вопрос пока остается актуальным

Comment: А если это в логи вывести? `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().toString()`

Comment: DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=720, height=1280, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=320.0, ydpi=320.0}

Comment: А вы знаете почему на некоторых устройствах плотность правильно просчитывается и изображение масштабируется правильно, а на некоторых нет? Пробовал кто то вникнуть в нативный код?

Comment: Замечу что displayMetrics иногда ширину и высоту тоже не правильно показывает

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych гляньте ответ, в вашем конкретном примере должно помочь.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по выдаче гугла на запросы по теме решения этой задачи не существует. Видимо придётся вам либо как-то без точной информации выживать, либо привлекать юзеров к вычислению. Т.е. помещать на экран предполагаемый по размеру круг (который должен быть размером с к-л популярную монету) и просить юзера жать на к-л кнопки для подгона круга на экране к размерам монеты.

Иного способа получить совсем точные параметры экрана нет. И не будет, т.к. никто не в силах помешать производителям железа создавать экраны с произвольными характеристиками и править системные API

Comment: Я бы не был так категоричен. PPI можно рассчитать исходя из разрешения экрана и размера диагонали. Трудность тут заключается в получении реальной высоты экрана. В самом простом случае можно получить высоту области экрана без учета статус- и боттом-баров, но если покопаться, то можно получить и их размеры. В итоге все сведется к простой формуле.

Comment: А может лучше ставить этот круг `invisible` и не просить юзера ничего нажимать а сделать это автоматом? А потом `gone`

Comment: в приложении аида64 диагональ и плотность получаю верные. там не просят от пользователя дополнительных действий
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9yubnhv8c9b5ula/Screenshot_2016-12-27-10-31-21.png?dl=0

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych, проблема в том, что лично мне не удалось с помощью гугла узнать как можно получить это число. Может они в к-л БД с моделями девайсов ходят и оттуда берут данные - чем чёрт не шутит)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб гляньте, моежт быть принесет пользу вам=)

Answer (score 3):

Ох уж это разнообразие размеров экранов...

Давайте разбираться как работает **AIDA64**. Нужно отдать им должное, у них очень большая база устройств с еще не менее малым числом уточнений для конкретных моделей. У меня получилось высчитать такие же значения для тестового телефона *Xiaomi Redme Note 3 Pro*.
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
    float my_LCD_Diagonal = 5.5f;

    WindowManager windowManager = activity.getWindowManager();
    Resources res = activity.getResources();
    Display display = null;
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = null;

    if(windowManager != null) {
        display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
    }

    if(res != null) {
        displayMetrics = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    }

    if(display != null && displayMetrics != null) {
        float xdpi = displayMetrics.xdpi;
        float ydpi = displayMetrics.ydpi;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            Point point = new Point();
            display.getRealSize(point);
            screenWidthPx = point.x;
            screenHeightPx = point.y;
        }

        int roundedXdpi = Math.round(xdpi);
        int roundedYdpi = Math.round(ydpi);

        float diagonal_ppi= ((float)(Math.sqrt(((double)(screenWidthPx * screenWidthPx + screenHeightPx * screenHeightPx))) / (((double)SystemInfo.DB_LCD_Diagonal))));
        if(diagonal_ppi> 1f) {
            ydpi = diagonal_ppi;
            xdpi = diagonal_ppi;
        }

        if(screenWidthPx > 0 && screenHeightPx > 0 && xdpi > 1f && ydpi > 1f) {
            float xmm = (((float)screenWidthPx)) / xdpi * 25.4f;
            float ymm = (((float)screenHeightPx)) / ydpi * 25.4f;
            float diagonal_in_inch = (((float)Math.sqrt(((double)(xmm * xmm + ymm * ymm))))) / 25.4f;
            String res_dpi = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d %s", Math.round((((float)Math.sqrt(((double)(screenWidthPx * screenWidthPx + screenHeightPx * screenHeightPx))))) / diagonal_in_inch), "dpi");
        }
   }
```

**P.S.** В результате получилось значение в `res_dpi` **"401 dpi"**.

**P.P.S.** Ввел данные, которые привел автор вопроса, получил значение **"294 dpi"**. Но этот алгоритм будет работать не для всех моделей телефонов!!! Потому как должны быть внесены поправки.

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych примите ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: почему не на всех телефонах будет работать? только на api >17 имеете ввиду ?   Я на сонную голову прошелся по коду. Зачем столько кода , если мы можем из системной инфы получить диагональ, знаем разрешение, что сложного по теореме пифагора рассчитать реальный density ? Я вижу что вы это сделали в самой последней строке, но такое вступление долгое)))  Я сейчас сам занят был задачей того как задать размер view в сантиметрах) но без точного density это никак)