# загруженное в битмап изоб. с разрешением 1920х1080, на всех дисплеях с fullHd разр. было на весь экран при загрузке изображения из mipmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, display, dpi

Что сделать, чтобы загруженное  в битмап изображение с разрешением 1920х1080,  на всех дисплеях с fullHd разрешением выглядело на весь экран при загрузке изображения из mipmap? 
Гружу из ресурсов fullhd изображение и в лог вывожу размер полученного битмапа , а битмап получается меньше. Вывожу в лог плотность , вижу 420. Проделываю то же самое на другом устройстве. размеры битмап получаю такие же как у загруженного изображения(т.е. все пиксели на месте) , плотность 480.  К слову в этом вопросе `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608243` обсуждается, но нет ответа на то почему так получается. 480 dpi не может быть если  FullHd разрешении экрана, при FullHD получается 400 пикселей на дюйм. В общем я окончательно запутался в том , где реальные величины , а где виртуальные.

Comment: FullHD смартфоны в основном попадают в категорию xxhdpi, а это `approximately 480dpi`, ссылка в ответе.

Comment: Но почему, когда я подключаю мой телефон в котором 400dpi (в интернете написано что 400 dpi, по расчету по теореме пифагора , если два катета (1920 и 1080) высчитываю выходит тоже в 400 dpi (а если вернее наверно ppi ) и ввожу в программе  DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); андроид показывает что 480 dpi , хотя на самом деле 400?  и поэтому он изображение начинает масштабировать.

Comment: Вот такой важный вопрос: А если экран смартфона 1920x1080 , то dpi каким будет ? 480? или может 400? я могу это посчитать зная диагональ экрана и разрешение ? Если по теореме пифагора при 5,5 дюймах получается dpi должно быть 400.

Comment: Вот тут описано https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Как я понимаю и писал ниже, телефон знает только к какой категории он отностится (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi). В соответствии с этой категорией, DisplayMetrics выдает фиксированные константы (hdpi = 240, хhdpi = 320, ххhdpi = 480). Никаких сложных расчетов.

Comment: Категорию прошивает производитель. Если он накосячит, все будет криво :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mipmap` предназначена для иконок

> Drawable files for different launcher icon densities.

Изображения для отображения независимо от плотности нужно помещать в папку `drawable-nodpi`

> nodpi: This can be used for bitmap resources that you do not want to be scaled to match the device density.

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: ну какая разница иконки или чуть большего размера изображения? допустим возьму с плотностью в 400 dpi  и положу в папку xxhdp и запускаю программу на телефоне с плотностью 400dpi , а андроид мне выдает что у телефона 480 dpi и иконку увеличивает. Андроид не может прочитать точную плотность пикселей экрана..в вопросе ссылка на недавний вопрос довольно опытного разработчика (относительно меня) и этот вопрос адекватного решения не имеет..

Comment: Все верно по той ссылки, телефон не знает сколько он dpi, он знает что он xxhdp, поэтому ищет xxhdp ресурсы, если их нет, берет по его мнению подходящие и масштабирует. Никакой сложной математики.

Comment: насчет mipmap, если написано что для иконок, то зачем туда пихать графические ресурсы и потом удивляться что работает не так как надо? Мне не понятно.

Comment: Так дело в том что ресурсов больше нет. Я специально поставил только в drawble-xxhdpi папку изображение ширина его 1080.  DisplayMetrics показывает DisplayMetrics{density=2.5, width=1080, height=1800, scaledDensity=2.5, xdpi=400.0, ydpi=400.0}      Почему 2,5 ? а не 3?  диагональ 5 , разрешение  fullhd, а коэффициент 2,5 почему то. В итого из ширины 1080 он делает 900 ..

Comment: Говоря еще проще , имею экран 5,5 разрешение 1920x1080 , в папке drawble-xxhdpi изображение разрешением 1920x1080. Загружаю его и он получает изображение 1600x900.  Если 1920 это 3x масштаб, а mdpi 1x, то разделив 1920 на 3 получим 640 , разрешение для mdpi. И это значение андроид умножает на 2,5 , а не на 3 и в итоге имеем 1600.. Зачем он так со мной поступает ((

Comment: 5,5 FullHD это как раз на границе xdpi и xxdpi, попробуйте `drawable-nodpi` папку.

Comment: 1080/2.5 = 432dp ширина экрана, для xxdpi ресурс должен быть 432*3 =  1296px шириной.

Comment: Ну и откуда у меня на экране 432 dp. У меня всего 400.  Это вычисляется по теореме пифагора  √(1080^2+1920^2)/5.5 = 400. Эта характеристика означает пикселов на дюйм. Реальных пикселов. Но в граф. оболочку бывает вшита и виртуаль. я характеристика, может она равна 480, как у меня и отображается. Надо просто понять с какими размерами работает андроид.

Comment: Так что это за значение 2,5 ? Если в оболочке програмно установлена другая плотность,  значит рисовать графику надо уже не в 1920x1080 а в еще большем разрешении и ложить в xxhdpi

Comment: Ну я пробовал папку nodpi , там то изображение шириной 1080 таким и остается. А если взять это же изображение из папки xxhdpi , то оно становится меньше. Значит система берет самую ближайшую по плотности папку и подгоняет размер, только что то хреново она это делает. Я предлагал две папки и nodpi и xxhdpi , он из xxhdpi взял и уменьшил. А оставил одну папку nodpi и естественно вложил туда то же изображение, система ничего не сжала и всё нормально смотрится

Comment: Сделал xxxhdpi папку и ресурс 1440 шириной. Система выбрала из папки xxhdpi ресурс 1080 шириной, сжала его . Чтобы на весь экран было остается в xxhdpi ставить ресурс больше 1080 , но это разве правильно?

Comment: Eugene Krivenja, выходит ,что ресурс из папки xxhdpi будет браться при коэффициенте плотности от 2 до 3. Если плотность 3, то для fullhd  ширина изображения 1080 в самый раз. Если у fullhd экрана плотность 2 , то ширина изображения должна быть 1620.  И тут появляется проблема..Закинул в папку изображение с шириной 1620 пиксель и оно нормально отображается, при плотности 2, а при 3 это изображение выйдет из рамок. Так? И приходится выкручиваться, где то mipmap чтобы растягивалось и сжималось, где то nine-patch.

Comment: Эти все вопросы лучше задавать производителю вашего телефона. Это он прошивает эти параметры. У меня, к примеру, классический Nexus 5, там никаких трюков, все работает как надо scaledDensity=3.0

Comment: И еще вы путаете ширину экрана в dp и плотность в dpi. Это разные параметры. Google рекоммендует производителям придерживаться стантартной базовой ширины в 360dp, ваш производитель сделал 432dp, отсюда и танцы с бубном.

Comment: Так вот открываю  AVD manager и выбираю из готовых виртуальных устройств этот самый Nexus 5,  4,95 дюймов экран fullhd , dpi написано 420 ..хотя рядом телефон с fullhd экраном и 5 дюймами и там тоже 420.. И не поймешь, что это за dpi вообще, т.к. реальный высчитанный по теореме пифагора равен 445. Если брать dpi по категории xxhdpi то он 480. Так что за 420 ? и в итоге scaledDensity=2.625 . и это Nexus 5 .

Comment: Я снова где то что то путаю.  У меня на телефоне fullhd и 5,5 дюймов (чаще всего встречающиеся параметры) В интернете в характеристках написано 400 dpi. По моему расчету так же и выходит. 400/160 = 2,5 . А в scaledDensity=3.0 и dpi написано 480. Я так понимаю это вшитые в оболочку производителем параметры. Экран он решил сделать 5,5 c fullhd , но виртуально подогнал его до 480 dpi.  ААА вооот в чем делоооо. Когда я в Adv выбираю nexus  5 , это я выбираю внешние параметры телефона, а андроид я заливаю в него из репозитория гугла(если правильно выразился)

Comment: И ясное дело это голый андроид без виртуальных корректировок dpi. Вроде я уже близко к истине. Осталось понять что за 420 dpi для nexus 5 в Adv manager стоят. ..

Comment: Где вы нашли 420 для Nexus 5? Не путаете с Nexus 5X? Я только вижу xxhdpi, 480 и в симуляторе и с помощью System Info на девайсе.

Comment: скрин эмулятора https://gyazo.com/aefa050f947487d80e1d8bfee18db957

Comment: Запустил ADV не через андроид студио , а из папки, там несколько иные значения,  у нексус 5 480 стоит и у многих близкие к рекомендуемым, но есть и такие у кого 560 dpi например. В общем буду на рекомендуемых dpi тестить. Скажите я ведь правильно понял, что реальный dpi может быть например 445 как у нексус 5(и в яндекс маркете так) и если посчитать по теореме пифагора. А вот dpi вшитый в оболочку уже 480

Comment: Да, все правильно. Математика тут не всегда работает :)